# How to expand tree view node when it's double clicked

Tags: typescript, treeview

I've been using a tree view component from material-ui. And I'd like to expand tree view children when it's double clicked, not just clicked. As i checked, there's no api to expand node children with double click.(https://mui.com/material-ui/api/tree-view/)Does anyone have ideas or tips?

My code is as below.

Thank you in advance.

```
`    export default function GroupTreeView() {

        const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState<string[]>([]);

        const handleToggle = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, nodeIds: string[]) => {
          setExpanded(nodeIds);
        };

        const renderTree = (nodes: RenderTree) => (
            <>
              <TreeItem key={nodes.id} 
                        nodeId={nodes.id} 
                        label={nodes.name}
                        >
                {Array.isArray(nodes.children)
                  ? nodes.children.map((node) => renderTree(node))
                  : null}
              </TreeItem>
            
            </>
        );
        
        const [data, setData] = useState(null);
       
        const fetchData = async () => {
          try {
            
            const jsonData = await SPClientService.getJson(jsonFilePath); 
            setData(jsonData); 
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Treeview JSON data error', error);
          }
        };

        useEffect(() => {
          fetchData();
        }, []);

       
        if (!data) {
          return <div>Loading.....</div>;
        }

        const handleExpandAll = () => {setExpanded(['root','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35']);
         };

        const handleCollapseAll = () => {
          setExpanded([]);
        };

              return (
                    <div className = "buttons">
                      <Button onClick={handleExpandAll}>Expand all</Button>
                      <Button onClick={handleCollapseAll}>Collapse all</Button>
                    </div>
                    <div className='TV'>
                        <TreeView
                          className='treeViewSection'
                          defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}                      
                          defaultExpanded={['root']}
                          defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
                          expanded={expanded}
                          onNodeToggle={handleToggle}
                        > 
                          {renderTree(data)}
                        </TreeView>
                      
                    </div>
              );
}`
```

```
`  const handleNodeToggle = (nodeId: string) => {
    setExpandedNodes((prevExpanded) =>
      prevExpanded.includes(nodeId)
        ? prevExpanded.filter((id) => id !== nodeId)
        : [...prevExpanded, nodeId]
    );
  };

   const renderTree = (nodes: RenderTree) => (
            <>
              <TreeItem key={nodes.id} 
                        nodeId={nodes.id} 
                        label={nodes.name}
                        sx={{marginRight:'5px'}}
                        onDoubleClick={() => handleNodeToggle(nodes.id)}
                        >
                {Array.isArray(nodes.children)
                  ? nodes.children.map((node) => renderTree(node))
                  : null}
              </TreeItem>
            
            </>
        );`
```

I tried above code, it works but it sometimes behaves strangely. (For example, clicking on a node that has not yet been opened will close the node above it that has already been opened, etc.)